# Why is this equality about the relative translation in the iterative closest point (ICP) algorithm obvious, and how can I derive it?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization, derivation

I'm a computer science bachelor student tasked with understanding **[On the ICP Algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220983893_On_the_ICP_algorithm)** by Esther Ezra, Micha Sharir, and Alon Efrat, and I'm having a lot of difficulty with even supposedly obvious claims. The setup is as follows, wherein we only look at translation, not rotation:

Let $A = \{a_1, ..., a_m\}$ and $B = \{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ be two point sets in $d$-space, for $d\ge1$, and suppose that the ICP algorithm aligns $A$ to $B$; that is, $B$ is fixed and $A$ is translated to best fit $B$.

At every iteration $i$ the ICP algorithm tries to find a relative translation vector $\Delta t_i$ that minimises its cost function, in this case the *root mean square*
$$\mathrm{RMS}(\Delta t_i) := \frac{1}{m} \sum_{a\in A} || (a + t_{i-1} + \Delta t_i) - N_B(a + t_{i-1}) ||^2,$$
where $||\cdot||$ denotes the Euclidean norm, $N_B(a)$ denotes the nearest neighbour of $a$ in $B$, and $m = |A|$.

The paper states:

> ##### Lemma 2.3
>
> At each iteration $i \ge 2$ of the algorithm, the relative translation vector $\Delta t_i$ satisifies $$\Delta t_i = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{a \in A} \left(N_B(a + t_{i-1}) - N_B(a + t_{i-2})\right),$$
> where $t_j = \sum_{k=1}^j \Delta t_k$.
>
> ##### Proof
>
> Follows using easy algebraic manipulations, based on the obvious equality that follows by construction $$\Delta t_i = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{a \in A} \left(N_B(a+t_{i-1}) - (a + t_{i-1})\right).$$

Unfortunately this ***obvious equality*** is not obvious to me, or at least not how I would derive/construct it.

Informally it seems plausible and intuitive to me that $\Delta t_i$ is equal to the average difference between the current and previous nearest neighbour of each $a$, but I'm not sure how I methodically arrive at this equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that "obvious equality" is not that "obvious", except for people who have solved one or more similar problems.

Here is a transformation formula, where $b=(a + t_{i-1}) - N_B(a + t_{i-1})$ and $c$ is some term that does not involve $\Delta t_i$.

$$\mathrm{RMS}(\Delta t_i) 
=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{a\in A} ||\Delta t_i +b||^2
=||\Delta t_i + \frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b||^2 + c$$

So, $\mathrm{RMS}(\Delta t_i)$ achieves its minimum value when $$\Delta t_i = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a \in A} \left(N_B(a+t_{i-1}) - (a + t_{i-1})\right).$$

Once that transformation formula is known, that equality should become obvious to you, since it is also your intuition that $\Delta t_i$ be "equal to the average difference between the current and previous nearest neighbour of each $a$".

---

Let see how we can prove that transformation formula. Recall that $m$ is the cardinality of $A$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{m} \sum_{a\in A} ||\Delta t_i +b||^2
&=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{a\in A} (\Delta t_i+b)\cdot(\Delta t_i+b)\\
&=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{a\in A} (\Delta t_i\cdot\Delta t_i + 2b\cdot\Delta t_i + b\cdot b) \\
&=\Delta t_i\cdot\Delta t_i + \frac{2}{m}(\sum_{a\in A}b)\cdot\Delta t_i + \sum_{a\in A} b\cdot b \\
&=(\Delta t_i + (\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b))\cdot (\Delta t_i + (\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b)) + c \\
&=||\Delta t_i + (\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b)||^2 + c, \\
\end{aligned}$$

where $$c=\sum_{a\in A} b\cdot b - (\frac{1}{m}\sum_{a\in A}b)^2.\quad\quad \checkmark$$